# The percentage of the rectangle in the other rectangle on leaflet map

Tags: javascript, algorithm, leaflet, gis, rectangles

There is a rectangle (we call it `A`) defined by two map points:

```
A = [southWest1, northEast1]
```

We also have a second rectangle:

```
B = [southWest2, northEast2]
```

where `southWest_i` and `northEast_i` - a point on the map, i.e. couple `[lat, lng]`

I want to find the best solution for **finding the percentage of the rectangle `A` in the rectangle `B`**.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as "percentage of a polygon inside another polygon". I think you rather mean *ratio between the area of a polygon and the intersection of that polygon with a second one*.

So:

- Calculate the intersection of A and B (let's call this C)
- Calculate area of B
- Calculate area of C
- Divide area of C by area of B

There are lots of ways to calculate areas and intersections of polygons. If you plan to use Javascript, I suggest you look at TurfJS, specifically at its [`intersect()`](http://turfjs.org/docs/#intersect) and [`area()`](http://turfjs.org/docs/#area) methods